# Trigger job only once and only when load is low

Tags: shell-script, scheduling

I'd like have automatic update of my gtags, but only when the system is idle.

To achieve this, I'm using `iupdate` to watch over the interesting parts of my source folder. But I have a problem with the "idle" part: I know that the `batch` command can run jobs when the load drops below 1.5 (or a configured value). But it may happen that `iupdate` runs `batch` multiple times before the job is executed which would lead to multiple gtags updates.

Of course I could create some lockfile and start `batch` only if it wasn't called before.

But is there some more standard method? I'm hoping for something like `batch_only_once` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it for you:

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release | grep -i desc
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04 LTS"
$ apt-cache show run-one
....
Description-en: run just one instance of a command and its args at a time
 This utility will run just one instance at a time of some command and
 unique set of arguments (useful for cronjobs, eg).
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build a wrapper script that will first parse the `atq` and prune other batched jobs using `atrm`.

Comment: Unfortunately, atq doesn't include the jobname. So I'd have to fiddle with job ids… Possible, but not elegant ;)

Comment: That, or build horrors involving `at -c` (which I did in the past, and not feeling shame, cause what're you gonna do).